# Getting messages from multiple chats madelineproto

Tags: php, api, chat, telegram, telegram-api

I am looking for some help here.
I am trying to get messages from multiple chats in Telegram using MadelineProto using the user IDs with code:

```
require 'vendor\autoload.php';

$settings[ 'logger' ][ 'logger' ] = 0;
$settings[ 'serialization' ][ 'serialization_interval' ] = 30;
$MadelineProto = new API('session.madeline', $settings);
$MadelineProto->async(true);
$MadelineProto->start();

$chat_one = 1234567; 
$chat_two = 3254682;
$chat_three = 154789965;

function getMessagesById($u_id, $MadelineProto){

    $offset_id = 0;
    $limit = 100;
    do {
        $messages_Messages = $MadelineProto->messages->getHistory(
            ['peer' =>$u_id, 
            'offset_id' => $offset_id, 
            'offset_date' => 0, 
            'add_offset' => 0, 
            'limit' => $limit, 
            'max_id' => 0, 
            'min_id' => 0, 
            'hash' => 0 ]
        );

        if (count($messages_Messages['messages']) == 0) break;
        
        print_r($messages_Messages);

        $offset_id = end($messages_Messages['messages'])['id'];
        
        yield $MadelineProto->sleep(3);

    } while (true);
}

getMessagesById($chat_one , $MadelineProto);

getMessagesById($chat_two , $MadelineProto);

getMessagesById($chat_three , $MadelineProto);
```

But this does not return any message. I tried it by setting async to false and I get the messages only for the first function call and not two others.

Any idea here, what I am missing?

What I am actually after is only getting messages from specifics contacts and the code above works with async set to false for only one contact. I use ajax to refresh it every 10 seconds for new messages but sometimes it returns empty, so any better idea to do this would be appreciated. I went through the docs but nothing helped on getting messages, all sendMessage.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is necessary to transfer the object:

```
$inputChannel = ['_' => 'inputPeerChat', 'chat_id' => $u_id];
 ['peer' => inputChannel,
```